# Can't resolve symbol. Validates resource references inside Android XML files

Tags: android, xml

I get an error on android:id="@id/question_text_view" located under TextView. How do I go about fixing this? 
Here is code for activity_quiz.xml   (Note, I took out the code for the buttons to save space.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:id="@id/question_text_view"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is code for QuizActivity.java

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;

    private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[]{
            new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_americas, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
    };

    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    public QuizActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);

        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,
                                R.string.incorrect_toast,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,
                        R.string.correct_toast,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "@+id/question_tv"

Comment: Thank you! What a stupid mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:id="@+id/question_text_view"` instead of android:id="@id/question_text_view".

> Add "+" near "@"